# Trouble with modifying wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working with modifying a Wordpress theme. The theme is named glare and i would like to do the following. (URL: http://tofsti.no/letsbuzz/)

Remove the background from the menu, so that only text shows. I have tried:

```
div.row.transparent{
  visibility: hidden;
}
#navigation .nav a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

But the visibility:hidden; hide the menu... 
What to do?

I would like to push the gallery images up (testgallery url: http://tofsti.no/letsbuzz/?galleries=test )  - a couple of px below the menu.
How to do this? I have tried:

```
div.row.col-listing{
  top: 200px
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following CSS for the menu and it should work:

```
header .transparent, #navigation .nav a {
    background:none;
}
```

Everything in your theme that has a class of `.normal` has a very large `margin-top` value (232px):

```
.container .normal {
    margin:0; /* or add whatever value works for you */
}
```

Comment: Worked great! 
Thanks alot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

question 1: Since the div contains both the text/links and the background it all disappears when `visibility` is `"hidden"`.

I'm guessing there is an `opacity:` setting somewhere, set to something like `0.5`.

Does removing the `background-color` value and setting the `opacity` to `1` work?